# How to fill in a missing value? - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to grab the number of citations of publications that are across different pages. Hopefully I can explain my thinking process clearly and the code is below:

```
import re

citations_list = []
searched_word = 'Citation: '

for url in final_list:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)))
    
    error = 'Citation: 0'
    
    if (results != None):
        for e in results:
            citations_list.append(e)
    else:
        citations_list.append(error)

print(citations_list)
```

Output:

```
[' Citation: 74', ' Citation: 13', ' Citation: 6', '  Citation: 4', '  Citation: 3', '  Citation: 6', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 14', ' Citation: 6', ' Citation: 26', ' Citation: 1', '  Citation: 2', ' Citation: 68', '  Citation: 68', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 11', ' Citation: 125', '  Citation: 45', '  Citation: 45', '  Citation: 6', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 21', ' Citation: 21', ' Citation: 18', '  Citation: 2', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 140', ' Citation: 6', ' Citation: 31', '  Citation: 8', '  Citation: 3', '  Citation: 6', '  Citation: 4', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 1', '  Citation: 2', '  Citation: 1', '  Citation: 1', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 45', ' Citation: 67', '  Citation: 44', ' Citation: 212', '  Citation: 2', ' Citation: 32', ' Citation: 14', '  Citation: 4', '  Citation: 3', ' Citation: 55', '  Citation: 20', '  Citation: 22', '  Citation: 2', ' Citation: 63', '  Citation: 28', ' Citation: 7', ' Citation: 1', ' Citation: 7', '  Citation: 1', '  Citation: 1', '  Citation: 1', '  Citation: 8', '  Citation: 7', ' Citation: 9', ' Citation: 3', ' Citation: 1', ' Citation: 8', ' Citation: 1', ' Citation: 21', ' Citation: 21', '  Citation: 7', '  Citation: 1', '  Citation: 2', '  Citation: 1', ' Citation: 4', '  Citation: 2', ' Citation: 41', ' Citation: 31', '  Citation: 51', ' Citation: 21', ' Citation: 80', '  Citation: 2', '  Citation: 12', '  Citation: 3', '  Citation: 31', '  Citation: 11', '  Citation: 8', ' Citation: 11', ' Citation: 29', '  Citation: 14', '  Citation: 14', '  Citation: 18']
```

The different pages to scrape are stored in a list called 'final_list'. The for loop is to go through each of these different pages to grab the citations. I'm grabbing the citations using regex and storing them in a variable called 'results'. As you can see it is successful at grabbing the number of citations for some of the pages.
The problem is firstly not every publication has a citation and so the regular expression does not appear. For those pages I would like to insert something like 'Citation: 0', just so that when I put everything in a dataframe, it is clear which paper had how many citations. There's obviously something wrong with my if statement so if anybody could see what it is, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. I am missing some things from the code. Is this the whole code? (if not, update). Does it work as expected with only 1 element in the final_list which you know with certainty that it has a Citation? Do you get the desired "results" from this one URL?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I've edited the question to add the output. It does work for every page that has a citation, so 91 out of 110. The remaining 19 pages are just skipped over. So yes I do get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! A friend of mine spotted my mistake:

```
import re

citations_list = []
searched_word = 'Citation: '

for url in final_list:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    results = soup.body.find(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)))
    
    if (results == None):
        citations_list.append('Citation: 0')
    else:
        citations_list.append(results)

print(citations_list)
```